# How to solve NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have a activity showing categories of places in a list view. When I am Trying tap on a List item, the app is crashing because of NullPointerException. Following is the activity

```
public class ListOfPlacesActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    public String tag_name;
    public List<NameAddress> nameAddressList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_places);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_places);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent!= null)
        {
            tag_name = intent.getStringExtra("CategoryName");
        }

        nameAddressList = null;
        try
        {
            final XMLDOMParserHandler parser = new XMLDOMParserHandler(tag_name.toLowerCase(), this);
            if(isConnectivityOn(this)){
                BackgroundRunner.doInBackground(new BackgroundRunner.DoInBackground() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute() {
                        try {
                            URL myURL = new URL("http://somewebsite.com/admin/data.xml");
                            URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
                            final InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    nameAddressList = parser.parseXML(is);
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                nameAddressList = parser.parseXML(getAssets().open("data.xml"));
            }
            ListOfPlacesAdapter listOfPlacesAdapter = new ListOfPlacesAdapter(this, nameAddressList);
            listView.setAdapter(listOfPlacesAdapter);
            listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnectivityOn(Context context) {
        boolean resCode = false;

        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            resCode = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resCode;
    }
}
```

From the error I came to know that my Apdater getting "nameAddressList" as a null because the code in doInBakground is not executed. So it's throwing NullPointerException. May I know how to solve this issue

Following is the error i'm getting :

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{asm.sdsuhood.app/asm.sdsuhood.app.places.ListOfPlacesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at asm.sdsuhood.app.places.ListOfPlacesAdapter.getCount(ListOfPlacesAdapter.java:43)
        at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:486)
        at asm.sdsuhood.app.places.ListOfPlacesActivity.onCreate(ListOfPlacesActivity.java:81)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You do realize that the data is null when you add it because it hasn't been downloaded yet by the background thread. Do you know how a thread works? You need to fill the listview inside the thread AFTER the data has been downloaded

Comment: @Pedro Oliveria I never worked before On Async Tasks and  Threading. Can you please tell me how to code this. Thank you

Comment: nameAddressList  is null unless you go into the else condition; maybe you're assuming incorrectly.

Comment: @Selvin clever explanation. I didn't see the link at first so got confused ;) Also, don't call `doInBackground()` directly, call `.execute()` on the task instance. And I don't see an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @codeMAgic My BackgroundRequest class extends AsyncTask and it's instance is created in BackgroundRunner class which is used in my code. When I try avoid doInBackround it's giving NetworkOnMainThread Exception

Comment: you need to put: all creating adater, setting it to listview code into onPostExecute, somehow, then nameAddressList should not be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your declaration and onCreate mthod be like this, so when you find get extras then call async class(Basically to do long duration operation on another thread).

```
ListView listView;
public String tag_name;
public List<NameAddress> nameAddressList;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_places);

    context = YourActivityName.this;

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_places);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        tag_name = intent.getStringExtra("CategoryName");
        new ListAsync().execute();
    }
}
```

Now, new ListAsync().execute(); this statement will call your async class where you ultimately call to web service and binds  data to List, this operation must perform on another thread.

After completion of that long task async class method onPostExecute executes and we make changes accordingly to reflect on unser interface.

```
    private class ListAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("test", "Running on ui thread");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i("test", "Doding long operation on another thread");
        final XMLDOMParserHandler parser = new XMLDOMParserHandler(
                tag_name.toLowerCase(), this);
        if (isConnectivityOn(context)) {
            try {
                URL myURL = new URL("http://somewebsite.com/admin/data.xml");
                URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
                final InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                nameAddressList = parser.parseXML(is);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            nameAddressList = parser.parseXML(getAssets().open("data.xml"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i("tag", "getting back to uo thread to update user interface");
        ListOfPlacesAdapter listOfPlacesAdapter = new ListOfPlacesAdapter(
                this, nameAddressList);
        listView.setAdapter(listOfPlacesAdapter);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    }

}
```

Let me know, if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: It's failing when there is no data connetivity because isConnectivityOn(ListOfPlacesActivity.this) giving error  "Class 'android.content.Context' is not loaded". So it's not going to else condition

Comment: May be your function is using context, so I have updated my answer and put context inside async.

Comment: It's not working. when i am trying to execute code with breakpoints for  isConnectivityOn(context) it's showing error on else part as non executable code